# would it ever make sense to modify a reference to a const char* passed in as a parameter to a method?

Tags: c++

Say I have something along the lines of:

```
int main()
{
    const char* someString = "Hello";

    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.modifySomeString(someString);

    return 0;
}
```

And two possible method signatures for `modifySomeString`:

**case A** `void MyClass::modifySomeString(const char* inBuffer)`

This seems straight-out pointless since I'd be getting a value so whatever I do with inBuffer does not affect the original someString in `main()`, right?

**case B** `void MyClass::modifySomeString(const char*& inBuffer)`

Here, I have a reference to the pointer so potentially I could actually modify the original "string" in main() (and probably should call the parameter inOutBuffer for clarity...). But besides the fact that I could cast to remove the const and modify the actual parameter inside my method... wouldn't this be just a bad thing to do?

I mean:

1. someString was declared const in main to start with, so trying to pass it to a method for it to modify it is nonsensical
2. inside the method, if I'm stating the parameter is const too, again it just seems wrong to then try and go around its const to modify it affecting someString in main.

Am I right about my observations on both cases A and B? Or is there a reason where it might be reasonable to pass a const string to a method and expect the method to still modify the original?

Personally, I think if I'm passing a const to the method, the method should instead have an out parameter where I get a new string without changing the original one. Something like:

```
void MyClass::modifySomeString(const char* inBuffer, char*& outBuffer)
```

But I'm interested in suggestions or someone explaining why it's perfectly fine to modify the const parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case A, you *don't* get a copy of the string, you just get a copy of the pointer.  You're right that it's pointless, because you can't change the characters (other than with `const_cast`, which you shouldn't use), and changes to the pointer itself won't be seen by the caller.

However, in case B, you have a reference to the caller's pointer variable.  You can't modify the string that it currently points to, but you *can* reassign it to point to an entirely different string, and when your function returns, the caller will see that different string through the variable.  That is, in a sense, "modifying" the string from the caller's perspective.

This can be a legitimate thing to do, but it's also a little strange, and you need to be very careful about memory leaks.  Make sure you're not causing the caller to lose its only pointer to the old string when you assign a different address to that pointer.

Comment: right. exactly. In the code I showed in main() there's only that one reference to the original string when it is initialized. So if my method were to reassign the pointer to a different memory address, on return, the caller sees its string as "changed" but has also lost the only pointer to the original, which is now leaked.

Comment: So bottom line, the most sensible thing to do seems to be, like I said, to have the signature include a second parameter through which a newly allocated modified version of the string is returned, right?

Comment: Typically you'd use a return value for that, not a reference argument.  But one way or the other, yes, you should pass the new string back to the caller in some way *other* than by replacing its pointer to the old one.

Comment: Yeah in this case I'd return the new string through the return value in the method, but I am being forced into the void return in the signature. Now.. what about this: say the original string is still declared as const char* as it is in my main() example, but now let's say my method signature does not include const. That is, it looks the same as my CASE B but without the "const" qualifier in the parameter. Then if the method changed the original value it would be "legal" and the caller would be "to blame" for passing in a const when the signature clearly shows no const?

Comment: The caller won't be *able* to pass a `const char *` to a function that takes a `char *`.  (Unless the caller uses something like `const_cast` to shoehorn it in, in which case it's clearly the caller's fault if something goes wrong.)  And it would be fine design-wise for the function to modify the string in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make a function that edits a variable, and especially not if it is constant. You are correct that it should create a new string.

Answer (score 0):

No.   The point of making the parameter const is that you are promising not to modify it.  And depending on your compiler, you may well be forbidden from doing so - not just warned.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behavior to modify any variable that is declared const. This means that if you use `char * mutable_ptr = const_cast<char *> (someString);` and then modify `someString` through `mutable_ptr`, the result is undefined. It could change the value, it could do nothing, your program could crash, or the compiler could replace the entire thing with a call to `format_hard_drive();`.

The only time it's safe to use `const_cast` to modify something you passed in as `const` is if you know that the value actually wasn't declared `const`. For instance:

```
void foo (char const * ptr) {
    // do something with a const_cast on ptr
}
int main () {
    char bar [] = "Cool!";
    foo (bar);
    return 0;
}
```

`bar`is not declared `const`, so it's safe to `const_cast` away the const qualifier in `foo`. Doing so, however, is almost always indicative of poor design. If you need to be able to modify a variable you pass into a function, then declare the reference without the `const` qualifier.

This being C++, all the usual statements about using `std::string` rather than `char const *` apply.

Comment: though your example is char const, my question was about const char, but still thanks

Comment: `char const` and `const char` are the same thing. I prefer the `const` after the type name for consistency with pointers / references. That way, the `const` always modifies the thing to its left. `char const * * const p` means that `p` is a constant pointer to a pointer to a constant character. Phrased another way, you cannot change where in memory that `p` points to (the pointer itself is `const`), but you can change the variable at that location, which happens to be a `char const *`. That `char const *` can change where it points to, but not what it points to.

Comment: You have to read declarations with const and pointers / references right to left.

Comment: sorry thought it was const * const <identifier>